# Confuse about the bitmap of XMM register

Tags: bitmap, sse

Sorry I don't have a good title...

I was reading this thread:   [Vector Matrix Multiplication In SSE](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/316546-vector-matrix-multiplication-in-sse/)

The original poster had the following code

```
// xmm0 = (v0,v1,v2,v3)
movups xmm0, [eax]

// xmm0 = (v0,v0,v0,v0)
// xmm1 = (v1,v1,v1,v1)
// xmm2 = (v2,v2,v2,v2)
// xmm3 = (v3,v3,v3,v3)
shufps xmm3, xmm0, 255
shufps xmm2, xmm0, 170
shufps xmm1, xmm0, 85
shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

Someone said the followings:

> But what really happens according to the manual: (a, b, c, d) means a are bits 0 to 31, b are bits 32 to 63 and so on

```
// xmm0 = (v0,v1,v2,v3)
movups xmm0, [eax]

// xmm0 = (v0, v0, v0, v0)
shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

This makes sense to me since in linear array model [elt0, elt1, elt2, ....]  elt0 is Array[0].

What confuses me is, according to the manual the bitmap of xmm register is [127...0] (see the picture below).

I was like the original poster looking at the bitmap and thought the leftmost of [elt0, elt2, elt3, elt4] was the bit "11".

So if I want xmm0 contains only v0

```
shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0xFF  // 11 11 11 11  === 0xFF
```

Which explanation is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be some confusion because bits in xmm registers (and all other registers BTW) are numbered right-to-left, i.e. the lowest bit is on the right, and the highest bit is on the left:

```
xmm0 = [bit 127, bit 126, ..., bit 1, bit 0]
```

If you consider the content of xmm register as 32-bit dwords, they are also arranged right-to-left:

```
xmm0 = [dword 3, dword 2, dword 1, dword 0]
```

The source of this confusion is that if you have an array in memory

```
float A[4] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
```

and you load this array into xmm register, the elements appear in the xmm register in the reversed order:

```
; xmm0 = (A3 = 3.0f, A2 = 2.0f, A1 = 1.0f, A0 = 0.0f) after the load
movups xmm0, [A]
```

Therefore, the right way to copy the first dword into all dwords in an xmm register is

```
shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

Also, if you want to do load-and-broadcast of a single float into all elements of an xmm register, for performance reasons it is better to use

```
; MOVSS can be much faster than MOVUPS, and is never slower
; Load A[0] into low dword of xmm0
movss xmm0, [A]
; Copy low dword of xmm0 to all dwords of xmm0
shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

AVX instruction set (supported in the recent Intel Sandy Bridge and AMD Bulldozer CPUs) has a special instruction vbroadcastss which performs load-and-broadcast:

```
; xmm0 = (A[0], A[0], A[0], A[0]) after execution of vbroadcastss
vbroadcastss xmm0, [A]
```

SSE3 instruction set includes a similar instruction MOVDDUP, which, however, only works for doubles

```
const double B = 2.718281828459045;

; xmm0 = ( 2.718281828459045, 2.718281828459045 ) after execution of movddup
movddup xmm0, [B]
```